# scanning a float, getting seemingly random values

Tags: math, floating-point, getch

I was given an assignment to create a procedure that scans a float, called getfloat.

for some reason, I am getting random values. If I enter "1" it prints 49.Why does this happen? And also, when i input values, I can't see them on the screen? when I use scanf for example i see what i hit, on the little black screen. but now the screen is just blank, and when i click enter it shows a bad output:

Example - input: -1. Output: 499.00000
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void getfloat(float* num);
void main()
{
    float num=0;
    printf("Enter the float\n");
    getfloat(&num);
    printf("\nThe number is %lf\n",num);
    getch();
}
void getfloat(float* num)
{
    float c,sign=1,exponent=10;
    c=getch();
    if((!isdigit(c))&&(c!='+')&&(c!='-')) //if it doesnt start with a number a + or a -, its not a valid input
    {
        printf("Not a number\n");
        return;
    }
    if(c=='-') //if it starts with a minus, make sign negative one, later multiply our number by sign
        sign=-1;
    for(*num=0;isdigit(c);c=getch())
        *num=(*num*10)+c; //scan the whole part of the number
    if(c!='.') //if after scanning whole part, c isnt a dot, we finished
        return;
    do //if it is a dot, scan fraction part
    {
        c=getch();
        if(isdigit(c)) 
        {
            *num+=c/exponent;
            exponent*=10;
        }
    }while(isdigit(c));
    *num*=sign;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

1) Your posted code does not match your example  "input: -1. Output: 499.00000", I get 0 due the lack of a getch() after finding a `'-'`. See #6.

1) 'c' is a character.  When you enter `'1'`, c took on a code for the letter `1`, which in your case being ASCII coding, is 49.  To convert a digit from its ASCII value to a number value, subtract 48 (the ASCII code for the letter `'0'`, often done as `c - '0'`

```
*num=(*num*10)+c;
*num+=c/exponent;
```

becomes

```
*num = (*num*10) + (c-'0');
*num += (c-'0')/exponent;
```

2) Although you declare `c` as a `float`,  recommend you declare it as an `int`.  `int` is the return type from `getch()`.

3) Function `getch()` is "used to get a character from console but does not echo to the screen".  That is why you do not see them.  Consider `getchar()` instead.

4) [Edit: delete Avoid `=-`. Thank-you @Daniel Fischer]

5) Your exponential calculation needs rework.  Note: your exponent could receive a sign character.

6) When you test `if(c=='-')`, you do not then fetch another `c`.  You also might want to test for `else if(c=='+')` and consume that `c`.

Good luck in your `C` journey.

Comment: The `=-` etc. form of compound assignment operators has been abolished _long_ before the first standard was ratified. `sign=-1;` has been an unambiguous `sign =  -1;` (only less readable) in all C compilers written in the last (at least) 30 years. ["In B and early C, the operator was spelled =+ instead of += ; this mistake, repaired in 1976, ..."](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html) Pedantic note: "c takes on the ASCII code for the letter" need not be true, it could also be EBCDIC (or a different encoding, but ASCII-compatible and EBCDIC are the only ones I know to be used).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I so rarely see a non-spaced `=-` that I, like you, was confident the it was obsolete.  My test of the code, _appeared_ though to do the `-=` function.  I'll can review that later.  True about "c takes on the ASCII ... need not be true" in general, but OP's "if I enter "1" it prints 49" certainly points to ASCII.  BTW, in ASCII or EBCDIC, (c - '0') does covert `c` to its numeric value.

Comment: My debugging of the code was faulty when I printed out `sign` after the `sign=-1;`  (I had assume it was an `int` type vs. `float`.  Saw a `0` and then assumed ancient (though now obsolete) `C` syntax.  mea culpa)

Comment: That `c - '0'` works for decimal digits is required by the standard (pity that it doesn't work for hexadecimal digits, would be super convenient if `'A' == '0' + 10` etc.). Yes, it's a pretty safe bet that the OP is working with an ASCII-compatible encoding, it was just a pedantic note ;)

Answer (score 1):

49 is the [Ascii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) code for the number 1.  So when `(0'<=c && c <='9')` you need to subtract `'0'` to get the number itself.

Answer (score 0):

A small hint: 49 is the `ASCII` for the `character` 1. You are using getch(), which gives you the return value `char`.